# Data arguments passing to user-defined function postgresql

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create user-defined function which will return **SUM** from expenses view based on given dates.

```
CREATE FUNCTION budget.getTotalAmountFromView (startDate DATE, endDate DATE)
RETURNS DECIMAL AS $$
DECLARE
    totalValue DECIMAL := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT INTO totalValue sum(amount) from budget.epenses_overview where transaction_date >= startDate AND transaction_date <= endDate;
    RETURN totalValue;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I am trying to invoke it using:

```
SELECT * FROM budget.getTotalAmountFromView(TO_DATE(20190201, YYYYMMDD), TO_DATE(20190225, YYYYMMDD));
```

But it returns error

AFTER CHANGES:
Function shall be assigned to the right schema -> budget;
and invoke:
`SELECT budget.getTotalAmountFromView('20190201'::DATE, '20190225'::DATE);`

Comment: *What* error does it return?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `FROM` for scalar function:

```
SELECT budget.getTotalAmountFromView22('20190201'::DATE, '20190225'::DATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are lacking single quotes around the date and format strings.

`TO_DATE(20190201, YYYYMMDD)` should be `TO_DATE('20190201', 'YYYYMMDD')`